# Пример MVC

Tags: mvc, php

Где можно посмотреть примеры для наглядного представления, на PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На примере фреймворка yii 2.0 код контроллера:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Blog();
        if ($model->load($_POST) && $model->save()) {
                return Yii::$app->response->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
        } else {
            echo $this->render('create', array('model' => $model));
        }
    }
```

Подробно [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/185236/).

Русский сайт по [yii](http://yiiframework.ru).

UPD:
[[@Etki](/users/16095/etki)](/users/16095/etki)
ничего напрямую из поста падать не должно. Вообще. Даже если на следующих этапах лишнее обрежется через safe attributes.-полнейший бред. Модель решает что и как ей делать с полученными данными.

Ставить else после return - моветон, захламляет код.- Если по логике продолжение кода не целесообразно при поставленных условиях - то для этого return и необходим. А по вашему получили результат - но оставшийся код нужно выполнить.

Comment: Простите, у меня прям подгорело от хабра

    $model->load($_POST) // прямой доступ к $_POST

.

    Yii::$app->response // какое отношение HTTP-сущность имеет к приложению?

.
    
    if ( .. ) { return } else { } // без комментариев

.

    echo $this->render() // эхаемый контроллер - горе в семье
.

    $this->trigger(self::EVENT_NEW_USER, $event); // почему event dispatcher'ом является какой-то левый класс

> использование `array()` в Yii 2, который на 5.3-то и не встанет

Тот волшебный случай, когда хабр, кодописатель и yii нашли друг друга

Comment: Улыбнуло))))
Для начала чтоб отгорело от кодописателя))
$model->load($_POST) // прямой доступ к $_POST - что в этом реально плохого?
Может вы мне (и всем остальным) тут покажите как по другому читать POST данные, таким образом чтоб к массиву $_POST принципе не обращаться. Другие Массивы содержащие данные запроса и функции обертки не предлагать.)
Да и в yii 2.0 есть обертка на получение переменной из данных запроса.

'использование array() в Yii 2, который на 5.3-то и не встанет' К вашему сведению Yii 2 минимум требует php 5.4. ) -тут опять мимо

Comment: @Ale_x

> тут покажите как по другому читать POST данные, таким образом чтоб к массиву $_POST принципе не обращаться.

Через фреймворк, в идеале через биндинг параметров экшена. Симфони умеет, например. Даже в первой yii был `app()->getRequest()->getPost($key)`.

> использование array() в Yii 2, который на 5.3-то и не встанет'

.

>  К вашему сведению Yii 2 минимум требует php 5.4.- об этом указано в доках) -тут опять мимо

найди десять отличий.жпг

Comment: $model->load($_POST) и  yii::$app->getRequest->getPost($name) (в YII2) - делают разные вещи. 
Зачем пробовать что-то ставить на 5.3, если требует минимум 5.4?

Comment: @Ale_x, не зачем ставить на 5.3, а зачем использовать старый синтаксис на том, что гарантированно не взлетит на PHP без поддержки нового. Про то, что метод модели и метод враппера запроса делают разные вещи - ничего не скажу, пожалуй. Я про прямой доступ к массиву `$_POST` и запихивание его куда попало целиком и без фильтрации.

Comment: $model->save() - вот тут валидация и 'фильтрация' происходит
$model->save(false)-   валидация и 'фильтрация'  НЕ происходит.
$model->validate() - тут тоже валидация и 'фильтрация' происходит

Comment: if ( .. ) { return } else { } // без комментариев - а тут что не так?

Comment: @Ale_x, ничего напрямую из поста падать не должно. Вообще. Даже если на следующих этапах лишнее обрежется через safe attributes.

Ставить else после return - моветон, захламляет код.